# iOS disabling all other buttons when another is pressed. Monophonic bass synthesiser using avAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, wav

I'm very new to stack overflow (with this being my first question) but I'm wondering if you guys can help.

I've made a bass synthesiser which works by playing back wav. files using avAudioPlayer, with each note having it's own player. I have placed multiple buttons on each note with different numbered tags and using a switch statement in order to give some control to the volume dynamics. There is also a segmented controller used to select from three different sets of samples using by selecting the prefix to the file name for the URL. The problem is if you try to play two buttons that play the same note and use the same avAudioPlayer the app crashes.

As this is a bass synthesiser you would expect it to be monophonic anyway, if only one button could be pressed at one time this could solve my issue. Does anybody have any idea how I would do this? Please use as basic terms as possible as I am not very familiar with coding. I will post the code for one note. (There are 13 for one octave).

```
#import "AJCViewController.h"

@interface AJCViewController ()

@end

@implementation AJCViewController

NSString* bassPrefix;
NSURL *url;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     bassPrefix = @"Z";
    // define default prefix for sample playback.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}




   - (IBAction)c1Pressed:(UIButton *)sender {


         NSString *bass = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@C", bassPrefix];
         NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:bass ofType:@"wav"];
           [bass release];
           c1AudioPointer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL     fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
           c1AudioPointer.delegate = self;
        // All buttons have tags, the buttons towards the top of the sceen having tag 0. The numbers buttons at the button 3. Switch statement varies volume based on where on the key it is pressed.
        switch (sender.tag)
        {

            case 0:
                [c1AudioPointer setVolume:0.4];
                break;

            case 1:
                [c1AudioPointer setVolume:0.5];
                break;

            case 2:
                [c1AudioPointer setVolume:0.6];
                break;

            case 3:
                [c1AudioPointer setVolume:0.8];
                break;

        }
        [c1AudioPointer play];
    }

    - (IBAction)c1Released:(UIButton *)sender {

        //While loop ramps down volume gradually to prevent clipping

        while (c1AudioPointer.volume > 0)
        {
            c1AudioPointer.volume = c1AudioPointer.volume - 0.1;
        }
        [c1AudioPointer stop];
        [c1AudioPointer release];


    }

    //De-allocate memory to free up audio buffer, necessary if note held till sample ends

    - (void)dealloc {

        [super dealloc];
        [c1AudioPointer release];
        [cSharp1AudioPointer release];
        [d1AudioPointer release];
        [dSharp1AudioPointer release];
        [e1AudioPointer release];
        [f1AudioPointer release];
        [fSharp1AudioPointer release];
        [g1AudioPointer release];
        [gSharp1AudioPointer release];
        [a1AudioPointer release];
        [bFlat1AudioPointer release];
        [b1AudioPointer release];
        [c2AudioPointer release];

    }



    - (IBAction)bassChoise:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

        //Switch statement selects sample group based on state of segmented controller

        switch (self.bassChooserSegments.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0:
                bassPrefix = @"Z";
                break;
            case 1:
                bassPrefix = @"Y";
                break;
            case 2:
                bassPrefix = @"X";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    @end
```

Thank you for your time. Any help or suggestions on what I should look up would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Look up IBOutletCollection.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to play different levels of the same note, and that is crashing the app?

I would speculate that the cause of the crash is that you are releasing the pointer twice, where the underlying cause is that you start play at one level, followed by starting play at another level, leaking the memory of the first avplayer.

You probably don't want to re-allocate it when simply changing the level on the fly. You are leaking memory if you don't release first in any case.

You could add a test to see if the note is already playing, and only change the volume.

```
- (IBAction)c1Pressed:(UIButton *)sender {
  BOOL isPlaying = YES;
  if (nil == c1AudioPointer) {  // Don't create new avaudioplayer if only changing the volume of currently playing note.
     isPlaying = NO;
     NSString *bass = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@C", bassPrefix];
     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:bass ofType:@"wav"];
     [bass release];
     c1AudioPointer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL     fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
     c1AudioPointer.delegate = self;
  }
  // All buttons have tags, the buttons towards the top of the sceen having tag 0. The numbers buttons at the button 3. Switch statement varies volume based on where on the key it is pressed.
        switch (sender.tag)
        {

            case 0:
                [c1AudioPointer setVolume:0.4];
                break;

            case 1:
                [c1AudioPointer setVolume:0.5];
                break;

            case 2:
                [c1AudioPointer setVolume:0.6];
                break;

            case 3:
                [c1AudioPointer setVolume:0.8];
                break;

        }
        if (!isPlaying) {
          [c1AudioPointer play];
        }
    }
```

If you do want to play the note again when sliding your finger for the different levels, then deallocate first.

btw. why don't you use ARC? You wouldn't run into this problem.